# Bad achive mirror during Server 16.04 install

Tags: 16.04, server, dns, mirrors

I'm currently trying to do a clean reinstall of Ubuntu Server 16.04.02. I've had varying success with previous installs. Sometimes it installs correctly first time, but has DNS issues when trying to update, other times it has issues during installation.

I know what the problem is, it is the default Ubuntu DNS settings (or those it appears to fail to get from my DHCP router).

When it fails during install, I get a red "Bad archive mirror" screen and cannot get past it. I can select other mirrors, or select to choose the network adapter at a later time, but either way, it still tries to connect to the mirror and fails and wont let me past. I've also tried skipping steps of the installation to get past it and it just fails or refuses to move forward without the previous steps.

When it fails after installation, it won't update, cannot connect to mirrors.
I know how to solve this problem, I just need to set the DNS to googles DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

How do I do this for when it fails during installations? Or how can I skip this step successfully so I can fix it after install? More importantly, how can I fix this properly so a system reboot/update doesn't overwrite my new DNS settings? Or even better, how can I get Ubuntu to play nicely with my DHCP router?

I've found a few questions related to the problem but nothing solving it and providing instruction for during the installation.

Useful info:

- Installing from Live USB made with Universal USB Installer
- Installing 64 bit
- First tried mirror: au.archive.ubuntu.com
- Fails with both wireless and wired
- Windows works with DHCP DNS settings (router == DNS server)
- Pinging au.archive.ubuntu.com from windows gives 202.158.214.106 as the IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered a solution for this problem. I don't know why this is the cause, but it seems to work flawlessly for all installs I've done since this problem.

**When building a Live USB, not all programs are equal.** I've tried many different methods with varying success, but one that I know **works on Windows is Rufus** https://rufus.akeo.ie/.

To check if your USB installer is the problem, do the integrity check on the main menu. If it fails, then you know the program failed to set it up correctly.

Programs I've used with varying success: YUMI, LinuxLive Usb Creator, UNetBootin, Universal USB Installer, and probably others. Although some of those were in the instructions on the Ubuntu site for installing from Windows, they don't always work.